# i am using IBM DB2 and While loading local host it says "Cannot connect to local host" and in the event viewer I am having this error

Tags: db2

I have installed DB2 and it is working fine but my database is connecting fine only when I try to load the GUI component to the browser I am not able to connect to the local host.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about the following phrases? `try to load the GUI component to the browser` and  `not able to connect to the local host`.

Comment: thanks but i have solved it already, the application id was not having the permissions to launch the local host.